# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined - discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a mute command that also sends an embed in a log's channel so it will be logged that a user has been muted. This is my error:

```
[Spuka#2670]: [mute]
/home/container/commands/mute.js:68
        channel.send(logEmbed);
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Here is my mute.js file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, WebhookClient, MessageEmbed, Bot, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

require('discord-reply');
const fs = require('fs');
const ms = require('ms')
const config = require("../config.json");
const ginfo = require("../guild.json");

const BOTTOKEN = (config.bottoken);
const OWNERID = (config.botownerid);
const PREFIX = (config.prefix);
const STATUS = (config.status);
const GUILDID = (ginfo.guildID);
const MODID = (ginfo.moderatorID);
const LOGID = (ginfo.logChannelID);

module.exports = {
  name: 'mute',
  description: 'This command mutes a member.',
  execute(message, args) {
    if (message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")  || message.author.id === (config.botownerid)) {
      const target = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (target) {
        let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');

        let MemberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

        if (!args[1]) {
          MemberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
          MemberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
          const muteEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle('Member Muted')
            .setDescription(`**User:** <@${MemberTarget.id}>\n**Moderator:** <@${message.author.id}>`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`Muted by ${message.author.tag}`, `${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
          message.lineReplyNoMention(muteEmbed);
          channel = client.channels.cache.get(LOGID);
          const logEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle('Member Muted')
            .setDescription(`**User:** <@${MemberTarget.id}>\n**Moderator:** <@${message.author.id}>`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`Muted by ${message.author.tag}`, `${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
          channel.send(logEmbed);
          return
        }
        MemberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
        MemberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);

        const muteEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('RANDOM')
          .setTitle('Member Muted')
          .setDescription(`**User:** <@${MemberTarget.id}>\n**Moderator:** <@${message.author.id}>\n**Duration:** ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter(`Muted by ${message.author.tag}`, `${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
        message.lineReplyNoMention(muteEmbed);
        channel = client.channels.cache.get(LOGID);
        const logEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('RANDOM')
          .setTitle('Member Muted')
          .setDescription(`**User:** <@${MemberTarget.id}>\n**Moderator:** <@${message.author.id}>\n**Duration:** ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter(`Muted by ${message.author.tag}`, `${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
        channel.send(logEmbed);

        setTimeout(function(){
          MemberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
          MemberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
        }, ms(args[1]));

      } else {
        const cmuteEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#F04848')
          .setDescription(`**${message.author.tag}**, you cannot mute that member.\nThe user may not exist or the bot may not have permission.`)
        message.lineReply(cmuteEmbed)
      }
    } else {
      const nopermEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#F04848')
        .setDescription(`**${message.author.tag}**, you are missing the "**MANAGE_MESSAGES**" permission.`)
      message.lineReply(nopermEmbed)
    }
  }
};
```

This issue has been happening with all of my moderation commands (ban, unban, mute, unmute, kick, clear). I believe the issue is that client is not being defined, but I'm not 100% sure why that is, as I have defined it at the very top of the code.
Anyways, let me know if anyone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must have client inside your parameters in execute()

Comment: When I try that, I get this error:

`/home/container/commands/presence.js:36
           client.user.setPresence({
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null
    at /home/container/commands/presence.js:36:24`

Comment: This isn't related to the ode you have shared. clearly, that is another file. You may create another question on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Few things I would like to point out here:

- The error in the question itself is caused as `client` isn't defined in the same file ( which is a bad practice and importing it from your mainfile within the execute function would help ), how?

```js
   <command>.execute(client, message, args); // in your main file
    execute(client, message, args) {... } // in your code files
```

- Error mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056026/typeerror-cannot-read-property-send-of-undefined-discord-js#comment122047888_69056048) comment, you may only call the `setPresence()` function on your client once it is in a `ready` state, make sure to add it under

```js
   client.once("ready", () => {...})
```

alternatively if it is some other file for example there is a `!setstatus` command exporting your client as a function parameter is your best option!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're trying to get the channel by doing `client.channels.cache.get(LOGID);`. The problem is that you haven't added the client parameter added in your execute command. What you'll need to do is add the client parameter to your execute function. You'll need to change the following things:

Somewhere in your main file you're calling the execute function of your mute file. What you now have will look similar to this:

```
require('./mute.js').execute(message, args);
```

You'll need to change this to this:

```
require('./mute.js').execute(client, message, args); // Change './mute.js' of course to the location of your file
```

After doing this you'll need to change the following line in your mute file to this:

```
execute(message, args) { // This is what you now have
// Change it to
execute(client, message, args) {
```

After changing this you're passing the client parameter to your mute file which makes you able to get the channel where you want to send your message in.

Also you'll have to remove the following line from your mute.js file

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

You won't be able to use this client because you haven't logged in to it. This does **not** mean that you need to login for this client.